# nginx wordpress xmlrpc protect from brutal attack

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I wish my xmlrpc.php only accessible by wordpress-jetpack and thrown 404 to anyone else

I tried

```
location ~ /xmlrpc.php {
      if ($http_user_agent !~* ".*jetpack.*") {
            return 403;
      }
}
```

I still get error when try connect my site from wordpress.com

```
2017/04/16 09:28:39 [error] 24200#24200: *1453 access forbidden by rule, client: 162.158.69.63, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php?for=jetpack&token=4xm%28
```

how do I create a redirect rules if $request_uri not contain "jetpack" then return 404 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just make a small, hm.. let's call it typo. You are using `$http_user_agent` in an attempt to check `User Agent`, but what you need to use is `$request_uri` or (as you specially ask for ) `$query_string`.

So Conf for xmlrpc location will work perfectly fine here.

```
    location ~ /xmlrpc.php {
        if ( $query_string !~* ".*jetpack.*" ) {
            return 404;
        }
    }
```